# Where is the emulator control in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In Eclipse I often use DDMS -> Emulator Control -> Location Control to read a KML file that I have which drives my LocationListener to playback a specific movement around the map (a trip).

I can't find the Location Control or even DDMS in Android Studio to do the same. I've read the docs at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/index.html.  Where is this function in AS?

Thanks, Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor-> Click on the emulator name in devicess-> Emulator Controls

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Guess I should have found that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `Android Device Monitor` in Android Studio ? If so its inside Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor. That is the same DDMS window inside Eclipse which you used to see